# I just want to run a Laravel's Migration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a lot of Migrations but I just want to run one.
I tried it many times, but every time all the Migrations were run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running one specific laravel 4 migration (single file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102197/running-one-specific-laravel-4-migration-single-file)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/selected/
```

Answer (score 0):

put migrations in more folders and run

```
php artisan migrate --path=/app/database/migrations/new_migrations
```