# Laravel 5.6: Migration from a specific folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to use `php artisan migrate --path="/database/migrations/ef` to use only the migrations in that path. But I got `"Nohting no migrate"` and the migration files are in that direction.

I tried to adding this to boot method in AppServiceProvider, that is from this link [Laravel running migrations on "app/database/migrations" folder recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641606/laravel-running-migrations-on-app-database-migrations-folder-recursively):

```
$mainPath = database_path('migrations');
$directories = glob($mainPath . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
$paths = array_merge([$mainPath], $directories);

$this->loadMigrationsFrom($paths);
```

But it does not work either.

Comment: Are you sure things aren't already migrated? Also, you don't really need to put quotes around the path

Comment: Completely sure, I just check several times.

Comment: Try `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: I wouldn't imagine a need to modify your AppServiceProvider the way you did. Using php migrate --path= should simply work out of the box...

Comment: I did it, I tried with: composer update, php artisan config:cache, php artisan view:clear, php, artisan cache:clear

Comment: Please check out similar post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47151886/how-can-i-run-specific-migration-in-laravel

Answer (score 11):

**for Laravel >= 5.0, the correct commands to migrate migration files in sub directories would be:**

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/ef
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/relations
```

Comment: This would work on older versions of Laravel. I believe versions below 5

Comment: Well sure, now that you've edited the answer this will work fine. Your previous answer before the edit was /app/database/migrations which was pre version 5

Comment: @Giovanni Just Change little bit like in removed app cause they changed path of database

Comment: I am using `php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/ef` but I got the same message

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Check his php artisan migrate --path="/database/migrations/ef double courts

Comment: Then you should add a note to the answer that highlight this change

Comment: Good luck brother but people will downvote since it doesn't answer the OP ;(

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it. (Not have "/" on first path)

I tried running the migrate creation command to find the error.

```
php artisan make: migration create_users_table --path=/path/to/your/migration/directory
```

Then composer dump.
Finally, I think the correct command to run in the sub folder is:

```
php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/subfolder
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to migrate spicific folder called User
**use** 
 `php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/User`

if you need to migrate all folders in migrations folder 
**use** 
`php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/*`