# Change default migrations folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have multiple databases setup. I want to change the default folder for migration run i.e. I want that if I run `php artisan migrate`. It should run the new migrations in `/database/migrations/master_database` instead of `/database/migrations` as I have migrations for child databases in main `/database/migrations` folder which I'm successfully running using `php artisan migrate --all`.

What I have done in AppServiceProvider:

`$masterDatabasePath = database_path('migrations/master_database');`

`$this->loadMigrationsFrom($masterDatabasePath);`

It works but it take migrations from both `/database/migrations` and `/database/migrations/master_database` folders while I want that it should only take migrations from `/database/migrations/master_database`.

Any Idea what I'm doing wrong or how it can be fixed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify folder for laravel migrations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55018704/how-to-specify-folder-for-laravel-migrations)

Comment: Depending on your implementation, you might use a similar solution to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641606/laravel-running-migrations-on-app-database-migrations-folder-recursively which sais you can add `$this->loadMigrationsFrom($paths);` to `AppServiceProvider::boot()` method

Comment: @Techno Yes it works but it take migrations from both `database/migrations` folder and `/database/migrations/master_database` as well while I want that it should migrations only from `/database/migrations/master_database`. Any idea?

Comment: My best guess is to make sure the `$paths` array should be literally: `['database/migrations/master_database']` the example I sent you was about recursive loading, you only want 1 path.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've achieved this by changing core Laravel BaseCommand.php file in:
`vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\BaseCommand.php`

Changings done in getMigrationPaths() function,
from this:

```
return array_merge(
    $this->migrator->paths(), [$this->getMigrationPath()]
);
```

To this:

```
return array_merge(
    $this->migrator->paths(), [$this->getMasterDatabaseMigrationPath()]
);
```

and then define getMasterDatabaseMigrationPath() function in same file:

```
protected function getMasterDatabaseMigrationPath(){
  return $this->laravel->databasePath().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'migrations/master_database';
}
```

Comment: Changing stuff in the `vendor` folder is never a good idea, as such a change would be lost after updating the package the file belongs to

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes, it is not a good idea, but I'm writing documentation to keep a track of it because I cannot find any other way to achieve the required results.

Answer (score 0):

```php
php artisan make:migration  "create users table" --path=/var/www/html/custom_migration

php artisan migrate --path=/var/www/html/custom_migration
```

Comment: Yes, it works but I want to automate the process i.e. If I run `php artisan migrate` it should run the migrations from `/database/migrations/master_database` so that I do not have to specify the path again and again.

Comment: would you can use laravel custom command https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck

Comment: @RamilHuseynov I've created custom command for child databases which run using `php artisan migrate --all` and it takes the migrations from `database/migrations` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to boot method in `AppServiceProvider`

```php
$mainPath = database_path('migrations');
$directories = glob($mainPath . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
$paths = array_merge([$mainPath], $directories);

$this->loadMigrationsFrom($paths);
```

Now you use can `php artisan migrate` and also `php artisan migrate:back`.

Comment: Yes it works but it take migrations from both `/database/migrations` and `/database/migrations/master_database` folder as well while I want that it should migrations only from `/database/migrations/master_database`. What I have done in AppServiceProvider: $masterDatabasePath = database_path('migrations/master_database'); 
$this->loadMigrationsFrom($masterDatabasePath); 

Any Idea what I'm doing wrong?